# Why is my power query only finding the first table on a wesbite?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to load 'Player Batting Data', which is the second table from this link: https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2023-standard-batting.shtml
However, when I copy the link into the power query, it only locates the first table, as seen below:
[Missing Second Table 'Player Batting Data'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOrBv.png)

Any known work-around? Essentially, I need current season baseball statistics to auto-update in my excel workbook.

I've tried copying the link directly to that table, but the same problem persists.